# Rows to Columns with iSeries DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a simple table with data as below:

```
col_1
==========
haddock
cod
hake
mackerel
tench
sprat
dace
rudd
pike
gudgeon
....
```

I want to select the data such that I can output it in 5 columns:

```
col_1     col_2     col_3     col_4     col_5
========  ========  ========  ========  ========
haddock   cod       hake      mackerel  tench
sprat     dace      rudd      pike      gudgeon
...
```

Is there a nice way to do this? NB iSeries DB2 SQL

Comment: How do you propose to decide which values go into which columns? What will determine which values go together in the same result row?

Comment: Arrival sequence. First 5 in first row, second 5 in second row etc.

Comment: There's no "first" or "second" (or any other "*th") row in a table, unless you order them by something explicitly.

Comment: What version of iSeries/System i, by the way?

Comment: @mustaccio on "V6R1M0"

Comment: _Why_ do you want to output in 5 columns?  Is this something that could be solved in display-layer code (especially if "result order" is unimportant)?

Comment: The data is not for display - it is an interface file. 5 columns is indeed ridiculous. Obviously the Italian Tax Authorities haven't heard of normalising databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which seems to work although not very elegant:

```
with tab1 as ( select col_1 as col_1 from my_table a where mod(rrn(a), 5) = 1 ),
with tab2 as ( select col_1 as col_1 from my_table a where mod(rrn(a), 5) = 2 ),
with tab3 as ( select col_1 as col_1 from my_table a where mod(rrn(a), 5) = 3 ),
with tab4 as ( select col_1 as col_1 from my_table a where mod(rrn(a), 5) = 4 ),
with tab5 as ( select col_1 as col_1 from my_table a where mod(rrn(a), 5) = 0 )
select tab1.col_1 as col_1, 
       tab2.col_1 as col_2,
       tab3.col_1 as col_3,
       tab4.col_1 as col_4,
       tab5.col_1 as col_5
  from tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 on rrn(tab1) + 1 = rrn(tab2)  
            LEFT JOIN tab3 on rrn(tab2) + 1 = rrn(tab3)
            LEFT JOIN tab4 on rrn(tab3) + 1 = rrn(tab4)
            LEFT JOIN tab5 on rrn(tab4) + 1 = rrn(tab5)
```

Comment: Good answer.  But did you try testing it?  (not that I can cast stones in that regard, lol)  But your WHERE logic looks like it may need to be tweaked.

Comment: If the number of rows involved is large, it may not be efficient to break the data up into 5 intermediate result tables which then have to be joined back together again.  But the proof would come in testing the different solutions at scale.

Comment: Mine is currently only working if the original number of records is a multiple of 5. Needs tweaking! Will tweak it and also test yours in the morning. Thanks :-)

Comment: One tip to address the multiple of 5 limitation, try using `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.  This style syntax is also prefered by many, in part because it can make the join conditions easier to follow.

Comment: @WarrenT , Yes - exactly the tweaking required! :-) It works now. In fairness to you I did also test your method. It very nearly works - except that the first row, column 1 is null.

Comment: You're going to end up with null values if you have any deleted records.

Answer (score 5):

To show what's going on, I'll break this down in small stages a,b,c,..  with "common table expressions", but this is one SELECT statement

```
with a as
( select row_number() over(order by order of f) - 1  as nb,
         col_1                    as fish
    from fishtable as f
), b as
( select smallint(nb/5)+1       as outrow,
         smallint(mod(nb),5)+1  as outcol,
         col_1                  as fish
    from a
), c as
( select outrow,
         (case when outcol=1 then fish else null end) as fish1,
         (case when outcol=2 then fish else null end) as fish2,
         (case when outcol=3 then fish else null end) as fish3,
         (case when outcol=4 then fish else null end) as fish4,
         (case when outcol=5 then fish else null end) as fish5
    from b
)
select  outrow,
        max(fish1)  col_1,
        max(fish2)  col_2,
        max(fish3)  col_3,
        max(fish4)  col_4,
        max(fish5)  col_5
   from c
   group by outrow
   order by outrow
```

The first step gives you an intermediate result of

```
    rn  fish      
======  ==========
     0  haddock
     1  cod
     2  hake    
     3  mackerel
     4  tench     
     5  sprat     
     6  dace      
     7  rudd      
     8  pike      
     9  gudgeon
```

The next step gives

```
outrow  outcol  fish      
======  ======  ==========
     1       1  haddock
     1       2  cod
     1       3  hake    
     1       4  mackerel
     1       5  tench     
     2       1  sprat     
     2       2  dace      
     2       3  rudd      
     2       4  pike      
     2       5  gudgeon
```

Then we spread the values out to separate columns based on the column number

```
outrow  fish1     fish2     fish3     fish4     fish5
======  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========
     1  haddock
     1            cod
     1                      hake
     1                                mackerel
     1                                          tench
     2  sprat
     2            dace
     2                      rudd
     2                                pike
     2                                          gudgeon
```

The last step squeezes the rows together by outrow number

```
outrow  col_1     col_2     col_3     col_4     col_5
======  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========
     1  haddock   cod       hake      mackerel  tench
     2  sprat     dace      rudd      pike      gudgeon
```

Of course that query may seem like a rather long way to write it.  I tested it out a bit larger scale, using a table I built of distinct first names. I then condensed my syntax down.

```
select max(case when mod(rn,5)=0 then fname else null end) fname1
      ,max(case when mod(rn,5)=1 then fname else null end) fname2
      ,max(case when mod(rn,5)=2 then fname else null end) fname3
      ,max(case when mod(rn,5)=3 then fname else null end) fname4
      ,max(case when mod(rn,5)=4 then fname else null end) fname5
  from (select fname, row_number() over(order by order of f)-1 as rn
          from firstnames f
       ) as a
  group by int(rn/5)
  order by int(rn/5)
```

Comment: +1 though it remains to the OP to judge if this is a "nice way to do this" :) Generally I'd agree with @Clockwork-Muse that such manipulation of results is better left to the presentation layer.

Comment: There is no 'presentation layer' in this case. The output is the file.

Comment: I'd use the ROW_NUMBER() function instead of RRN, as ROW_NUMBER() numbers the result set and RRN is the physical relative record number which could be missing values if there are any deleted records.

Comment: @Charles good point. But the request was for arrival sequence, and my concern would be that ROW_NUMBER() without an ORDER BY clause assigns the ranking arbitrarily. I would therefore put `OVER ( ORDER BY ORDER OF f )` or `OVER (ORDER BY rrn(f))`

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect suggestions and testing, plus added a shorter more practical version for those of us who don't like so much typing ;-)

Comment: @Peter the null in col_1 of the first result row was caused by its row number being calculated as 1, so the first row had no mod zero.  I solved this by subtracting 1 when calculating rn.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want seperate COLUMNS or do you just want the data to be a single column that contains the values of five rows. If you want the later, try something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( a.col_1 SEPARATOR ' ' )
  FROM (SELECT ( (@ROWNUM := CASE WHEN @ROWNUM IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @ROWNUM + 1 END) DIV 5 ) AS group_num, col_1
          FROM your_table) a
 GROUP BY a.group_num;
```

If you want the former, tyy something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.row_num MOD 5 = 0 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '' ) AS col_1
      ,GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.row_num MOD 5 = 1 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '' ) AS col_2
      ,GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.row_num MOD 5 = 2 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '' ) AS col_3
      ,GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.row_num MOD 5 = 3 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '' ) AS col_4
      ,GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN a.row_num MOD 5 = 4 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '' ) AS col_5
  FROM (SELECT @ROWNUM := CASE WHEN @ROWNUM IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @ROWNUM + 1 END AS row_num, col_1
          FROM your_table) a
 GROUP BY a.row_num DIV 5;
```

See SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc42/9

Sorry, just noticed you were looking for a solution for iSeries DB2 SQL (not MySQL). DB2 would require a different solution.

If you have the DB2 LISTAGG function available, you could try something like (sorry don't have a way to test it so it may not be perfect):

```
SELECT LISTAGG( CASE WHEN MOD(a.row_num, 5) = 0 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END, '' ) AS col_1
      ,LISTAGG( CASE WHEN MOD(a.row_num, 5) = 1 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END, '' ) AS col_2
      ,LISTAGG( CASE WHEN MOD(a.row_num, 5) = 2 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END, '' ) AS col_3
      ,LISTAGG( CASE WHEN MOD(a.row_num, 5) = 3 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END, '' ) AS col_4
      ,LISTAGG( CASE WHEN MOD(a.row_num, 5) = 4 THEN a.col_1 ELSE '' END, '' ) AS col_5
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() AS row_num, col_1
          FROM your_table) a
 GROUP BY INT(a.row_num / 5);
```

Notes:

1) There are alternatives to using LISTAGG (like XMLAGG). Search this forum for DB2 GROUP_CONCAT alternatives. There are many examples.

2) if you don't have ROW_NUMBER() available, it can be simulated in DB2 using recursive SQL.

Comment: Yes, no fancy GROUP_CONCAT functions on iSeries :-(

Comment: what version of DB2 are you running? Do you have you LISTAGG function available?

Comment: Operating on "V6R1M0"

Comment: @gwc iSeries is the former name for a hardware product line which is has been incorporated into Power Systems running an OS now called IBM i.  DB2 is tightly integrated into the OS, such that the DB2 version numbers reflect the OS, and are totally unrelated to DB2 LUW or z/OS release numbers. You may view the list of functions on the IBM i Information Center [v6.1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzintro.htm) or the current [v7.1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm).

Comment: @gwc I'm not a MySQL expert, but I don't see how this makes sense in that environment either.  Remember, Peter asked for 5 separate result columns, so why would you be trying to concatenate anything?

Comment: @WarrenT check the SQLFiddle - works just fine on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Example from IBMi SQL reference (v7r3):

Produce an alphabetical list of comma-separated names, grouped by department:

SELECT workdept,
LISTAGG(lastname, ’, ’) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lastname)
AS employees
FROM emp
GROUP BY workdept;

Generates the following result:

WORKDEPT EMPLOYEES

A00 HAAS, HEMMINGER, LUCCHESSI, O’CONNELL, ORLANDO

B01 THOMPSON

C01 KWAN, NATZ, NICHOLLS, QUINTANA
.....

Clean, works.

Comment: The problem here is that, from OP's problem description, there's no equivalent of `workdept`, so all items would end up in the same "group" (all in the same row).  Then, too, `LISTAGG` puts the rows into the same (delimited) column, whereas the OP was wishing for actual separate nameable columns.  The correct operator would be an equivalent to SQL Server's `PIVOT`, which last I was aware is not available yet.